# The usage of "sic" in writing

Tags: writing, quotations

I have seen many articles that use quotes from players like:

> We gonna [sic] be working hard over the summer cause we gotta [sic] get better.

What is *sic*? Where does it come from?

Comment: Related: _[Can you use “(sic)” in other contexts?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16649/5822)_

Comment: Why is there a [sic] after `gotta`? I can understand the first one, the missing `are`, but if `gotta` is considered an "error" because it's slang then why doesn't `cause` have [sic] as well?

Comment: @Kop: That was copied from an article I read on-line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*sic* is Latin (so, thus) and is used to call attention to an error in an original quote.  Specifically, it is used when quoting another to say, "this is not a typographical, spelling or grammar error on the part of the reporter; rather, the error was in the original, and we're quoting it without change."

Comment: Correct. It is, however, exceedingly difficult to employ "[sic]" properly, without giving the appearance of sneering or looking down at the person or item quoted. It is for this reason that Fowler, Gowers, et al., caution against its use. It is common for publishers, therefore, to simply make a silent editorial correction and remove the fault in question.

Comment: Indeed, in the cited example, the *sic* is most certainly used in a sneering manner. A single use at the end of the quotation is enough.

Comment: @TheRaven: Agreed. It would seem good practice to silently correct unless the error could be relevant or interesting. This includes mockery, analysing the error or the style of the original author, and quotes in legal texts.

Comment: I once represented a professor who thought "sic" meant "spelling incorrect." He was confused as to why I used it in a legal brief.

Answer (score 4):

It's [from the Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sic) *sic* (so, thus). Etymonline dates it back to 1887.