# What does [sic] mean in an article

Tags: meaning

I have been looking for this in the internet for a while now. 
I recently read another article about [Nuking Hurricanes](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2016/11/hurricanes-weather-history-nuclear-weapons/)

Please see the **[sic]** in this quote below

> Could Hurricane Carla have been broken up, or greatly modified, or its
>   course turned back to sea, by nuclear bombs?,” asked an editorial in
>   the Longview Daily News. “The suggestion that man-made explosions may
>   effect [sic] hurricanes cannot be dismissed with the same degree of
>   certainty on the basis of energy comparisons as was possible with
>   earlier atomic weapons.

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28935/the-usage-of-sic-in-writing

Comment: In this case, the author is marking an error where the author used *effect* instead of *affect*.

Comment: In a quotation -- something the writer is not responsible for saying, only quoting correctly -- the writer may insert `[sic]` after an error made  in the quotation, to indicate that the error was in the original, not the transcription. _Sic_ is Latin for _thus_ or _so_, and can be thought of as 'exactly so'.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin and John, now I get it. Hence it mostly appears in somebody else writing mentioned in quotes.

Comment: In this *particular* example I'm not sure exactly why *[**sic**]* is included. Maybe the (citing) author is trying to call attention to the "error". Or maybe he's *confirming* the original (cited) author's intended meaning (that nuclear explosions might ***effect = cause** [to come into existence]* hurricanes, as opposed to ***affect =  modify** [the behaviour of hurricanes]*. Not a very helpful bit of background info to the quote, I feel.

Comment: @FF I disagree; ' "Could Hurricane Carla have been broken up, or greatly modified, or its course turned back to sea, by nuclear bombs?,” asked an editorial in the Longview Daily News. ' strongly implies that 'affect' was intended in the next sentence. And 'cause' vastly outperforms 'effect'.